# Django admin actions in detail view?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a few admin actions defined in my (fairly standard) Django app. Some of those actions would also make a lot of sense if they were available on the detail page of an object.

Right now, users would need to navigate back to the list, then search for the specific record, then trigger the action.

Is there a way to expose this functionality on the detail page as well?

Comment: Please select a correct answer or provide one yourself

Answer (score 7):

[Here](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/custom_button.html) is the answer you're looking for.

Essentially, you create a *yourmodel_changeform.html* file with following contents:

```
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}

{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <div class="submit-row">
        <input type="submit" value="Button Label" name="_your-action-name">
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

And then override the *response_change* method on your ModelAdmin class and set the change_form_template attribute.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    change_form_template = "templatelocation/yourmodel_changeform.html"

    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        if "_your-action-name" in request.POST:
            # do whatever you want the button to do
            obj.name = "new name"
            obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(".")  # stay on the same detail page
        return super().response_change(request, obj)
```

Tested on Django 3.0.3

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you right, what you need to do is to write some separate html and then use it on different pages with `{% include '/path/foo.html' %}`. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#include) is more on this topic.

In `foo.html` you can add any functionality you want to use on different pages(forms, links, etc.).

If you want more detailed answer, it would be nice to see your code and what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score -1):

To elaborate pythad.

1 Add another simple html that extends your admin html's and holds the buttons describing the admin action. you may call it change_form.py
make sure to strt is with:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
```

2 you would need to add small functions in your admin.py to conect the buttons to the action functions.
somthong like :

```
        try:
            sr = Scenario.objects.filter(pk = pk)
            queitem = QueueScript.objects.filter(scriptresult__pk=sr.scriptreport.pk)
        #do somtho

        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META["HTTP_REFERER"])
```

3 you need to elaborate/override the admins get_urls function to know the functions from above:

```
def get_urls(self, ):
    urls = super(ScenarioAdmin, self).get_urls()
    my_urls = patterns("",
        url(r"(?P<pk>\d+)/stop_my_script/$",
                           self.stop_my_script),
        url(r"(?P<pk>\d+)/run_scenario_standalone/$",
                           self.run_scenario_standalone),
                       )

    return my_urls + urls
```

4 and finally elaborate your change_view func also in admin.py

```
  def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        extra_context = {}
        extra_context['show_scer_buttons'] = True
        extra_context['is_running'] = self.choose_template_buttons(object_id, extra_context)
        return super(ScenarioAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id,
            form_url, extra_context=extra_context)
```